# Text version of mail processed after HTML version, why?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

Understanding that the subjectline is rendered last and the preheader first is quite useful when understanding how you can easily manipulate the subjectline with AMPscript, but it's quite hard when it comes to the Preheader as it's rendered differently and before AMPscript placed in the body.

This leaves me curious though, when it comes to the rendering of the HTML and Text version of the email itself.

I understand [the order of Email component rendering](https://ampscript.guide/order-of-operations/) in SFMC is

1. Preheader
2. HTML version
3. Text version
4. Subjectline

Can anyone explain why HTML version is 2nd and Text version is 3rd and if it would matter if they switched places?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation states that "email components are interpreted in the following order..." This is not open to configuration and does not depend on the source code order. That is the order in which the parts will be interpreted. In other words, the text version will never be rendered before the HTML version. This likely has to do with [RFC 1341](https://email%20components%20are%20interpreted%20in%20the%20following%20order), which describes how the most preferred content is placed in an email (hint: HTML goes first).

Comment: Thank you, makes perfect sense. 
I assume the link you're referring to is this, right? https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1341

Comment: As an additional note: I didn't really want to change or manipulate the order of processing, just wanted to understand :)

Comment: @FelixSanchez Yes, it's a Request for Comments, which describes how some particular file or protocol works on the Internet. RFC 1341 deals with multipart messages, such as HTML/text emails. It's not necessary for you to read it, but I like to point them out when it makes sense for people who might be interested.